# Объясните, пожалуйста, отсутствие одной запятой и присутствие второй

Tags: пунктуация

> Зависнув на секунду, я выбираю: первую врубить или телефон брать и
>   ведь чую, что уже качусь назад, но все-таки поднимаю трубку, потому
>   что даже не в теме, куда опаздываю.

Здесь вот со знаками всё ли в порядке:

*...я выбираю: первую врубить или телефон брать и ведь чую, что...*

И вот здесь:

*...не в теме, куда опаздываю.*

СПАСИБО!

Comment: Отсутствие первой объясняю опечаткой. )) А со второй разве не все в порядке? Вот если бы было: "опаздываю, но не помню куда" – тогда конечно.

Comment: Милый Ние, здравствуй, обратно же! Это Я ПРАВЛЮ ТЕКСТ; знак перед *и ведь чую* я обязана понимать... Тут бы ссылку на правило.

Comment: "и ведь чую..." - явное присоединение, правда, неожиданности его не вижу, поэтому можно  и запятую, и тире. Даже точкой можно предложение разделить. А вторая запятая нужна, потому что придаточное не состоит из одного союзного слова, есть и сказуемое.

Comment: Люсенька, благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)Зависнув на секунду, я выбираю: (2)первую врубить или телефон брать  ―  и  (3) ведь чую, (4)что уже качусь назад, но все-таки поднимаю трубку, (5) потому что даже не в теме (там), (6)куда опаздываю.

**Пояснения**

1) Предложение состоит **из двух частей, разделенных тире** перед сочинительным союзом И.

Розенталь (тире в ССП) [XXVII. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В СЛОЖНОСОЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm);

2) чую, но поднимаю – однородные сказуемые в предложении 3;

3) не в теме (там), куда опаздываю – придаточное места с пропущенным указательным словом ТАМ.

Comment: Сиби, спасибо, тире объяснено; меняет ли ситуацию со второй запятой иной, чем Вы прочли, смысл: героиня не в теме куда опаздывает, ей в тысячу мест надо одновременно, опаздывает везде, - я объяснила? По-русски: не знаю, куда опаздываю.

Comment: "Не в теме" ~ "не знаю". "Даже не знаю, куда опаздываю" – запятая ведь нужна?

Comment: Запятая нужна в любом случае, а семантику можно определить из контекста, в том числе если "не знаю, куда опаздываю).